# std::copy из бинарного файл в std::vector<int>

Tags: c++

Возникла необходимость переписать проект на STL. В старой версии имелось вот такое считывание в массив `int` из бинарного файла:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++)            
            in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&ia[i]), sizeof(int));
```

Пытался переписать следующим образом:

```
std::ifstream ifs(nameFile, std::ios::binary);
std::istream_iterator<int> ii(ifs);
std::copy(ii, std::istream_iterator<int>(), ia.begin());
```

Вектор `ia` остается пустым. Поиск в гугле результатов не дал, все примеры почему-то не работают. Помогите разобраться (p.s. память под вектор выделена).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::istream_iterator` используется для текстового ввода, т.к. работает через вызов `operator>>`. Для бинарного чтения из файла в вектор нужно использовать `read`, который у Вас уже был:

```
ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ia.data()), ia.size() * sizeof(int));
```